# regular/context free grammar

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, regular-language

Im hoping someone can help me understand a question I have, its not homework, its just an example question I am trying to work out. The problem is to define a grammar that generates all the sums of any number of operands. For example, 54 + 3 + 78 + 2 + 5... etc. The way that I found most easy to define the problem is:

```
non-terminal {S,B}
terminal {0..9,+,epsilon}

Rules:

S -> [0..9]S
S -> + B
B -> [0..9]B
B -> + S
S -> epsilon
B -> epsilon 

epsilon is an empty string.
```

This seems like it should be correct to me as you could define the first number recursively with the first rule, then to add the next integer, you could use the second rule and then define the second integer using the third rule. You could then use the fourth rule to go back to S and define as many integers as you need.

This solution seems to me to be a regular grammar as it obeys the rule A -> aB or A -> a but in the notes it says for this question that it is no possible to define this problem using a regular grammar. Can anyone please explain to me why my attempt is wrong and why this needs to be context free?

Thanks.

Comment: Please first notice that, in your grammar, there may be a hanging `+` on the right side. If the first `B` is empty, then `1+` is a valid sentence, which I don't think is what you're intending.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not the correct definition, it's easier to think that for a language to be non-regular it would need to balance something (like parenthesis).

Your problem can be solved using direct recursion only on the sides of the rules, not in the middle, so it can be solved using a regular language. (Again, this is not the correct definition, but it's easier to remember!)

For example, for a regular expression engine (like in Perl or JavaScript) one could easily write `/(\d+)(\+(\d+))*/`.

You could write it this way:

```
non-terminal {S,R,N,N'}
terminal {0..9,+,epsilon}

Rules:

S -> N R
S -> epsilon

N -> [0..9] N'
N' -> N
N' -> epsilon

R -> + N R
R -> epsilon
```

Which should work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Paulo, your explaination that non-regular grammars generally are ones that need to be balanced makes sense and is a big help. One thing that confuses me about your suggested solution is that I thought that regular grammars could only have a terminal or a terminal and a non terminal on the right side of the rule.e.g. A -> aB. Your first rule for S has two non-terminal symbols on the right hand side (also the first rule for R -> + N R). Does this not mean that the language defined is context-free?

Comment: No, the language is still regular. Actually I used `S -> N R` because the non-terminal `N` defines a number. Though it is a good practice (when learning) to use the first item on a non-terminal as a terminal, this is not necessary. You could easily rewrite it to replace that first `N` to terminals (e.g., `S -> [0..9] N' R`). The way I wrote it avoids duplicating code when it was not needed. Notice that there isn't recursion on the middle of any expression.

Answer (score 0):

The language is regular. A regular expression would be:

```
((0|1|2|...|9)*(0|1|2|...|9)+)*(0|1|2|...|9)*(0|1|2|...|9)
```

Terminals are: {0,1,2,...,9,+}

"|" means union and * stands for Star closure

If you need to have "(" and ")" in your language, then it will not be regular as it needs to match parentheses.
A sample context free grammar would be:

```
E->E+E
E->(E)
E->F
F-> 0F | 1F | 2F | ... | 9F | 0 | 1 | ... | 9
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I am starting to understand, one question I have about your context-free example is that is it the case that because you have the rule E -> E+E the language may be ambiguous?

Comment: Actually the grammar I wrote, IS ambiguous, because for example the string 1+2+3 has two different derivation trees. The language is **NOT** ambiguous, since we can write a non ambiguous grammar for it.